# H2 database growing out of control quickly

Tags: java, database, h2

Hi hopefully someone can help me, I am currently running a H2 database that when cached grows out of control quickly. After completing the cache I found it should be about 32MB but after a small stretch of time it has grown to be nearly 5GB. I have created a copy and dropped the tables one at a time to try and determine what is causing this and it had no effect, leading me to believe it is storing metadata or something else automatically that I can't see but I still can't figure out how it could grow exponentially. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a SQL script to check what the database contains (using the SCRIPT statement).

If there is not much data in the SQL script, it could be a long running open transaction that prevents the transaction log from shrinking. To analyze this, run the [Recover tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Recover.html) and check if there is an open transaction (see the "transaction log" section).